# Digital Signature on Audio files

Tags: security, audio, upload, certificate, digital-signature

I am just wondering if anybody here would have any clue how to assign a digital signature or unique ID to an audio file being uploaded to a music community website like soundcloud? I am doing it as a project in college and haven't found any useful information just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to exactly identify a particular audio file to the individual bit or identify a the contents of the file?  The application of the latter is generally used to protect rights, identify copyright infringement, or work out who is paid royalties.

If it is the latter you are after, what you need here is an audio fingerprint.  Rather than calculate a hash over the data of the audio file, you calculate a hash over audio features - ideally ones which are resilient to rudimentary transformations such as truncation, decoding (and subsequent re-encoding), speed changes or gain changes.  All of which will defeat a hash of the audio file.

This is an active research topic.  You might we well advised to search academic literature for audio feature extraction and audio fingerprinting.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to see the standard for digital signing of audio files. Potentially you can embed the signature into MP3 tags (and maybe to tags in other file formats), but this is not standard and requires knowledge of both file format and PKI. And then only your software will understand the signature.

Another option is to create detached signatures. In this case your possibilities are countless - you can use PKCS7/CMS or XML signing. Detached signatures are stored separately from the original data, thus the music file is not modified in any way.